# tinymce: disable typing inside an inserted tag and offset cursor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to insert any tag (let's call it a cut-tag) that divide publication into 2 parts. I would like this tag to be visible.
[image]

I implemented the simple custom plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('cuttag', function(editor, url) {

// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('cuttag', {
    text: false,
    image: url + '/icon/cuttag.png',
    tooltip: 'Insert cut-tag',
    onclick: function() {
        editor.insertContent('<span class="cut-tag">&nbsp;</span>');
    }
   });
});
```

And include my own content_css

```
.cut-tag {
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #000000;
position:relative;
}

.cut-tag:after{
   position:absolute;
   content:'a cutting line';
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

But when I'm trying to put smth else tynymce insert text inside this fake span and more over, when I press enter it copies this tag again and again.
[image]

Could anyone help me fix code. Is there another way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was very simple.
TinyMCE has `noneditable` plugin. I include it and add to an inserted element class 'mceNonEditable'

```
 <TinyMCE config={{
           plugins: 'noneditable',
           // ... the rest of settings
        }}/>
```

And plugin looks like

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('cuttag', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('cuttag', {
    text: false,
    image: url + '/icon/cuttag.png',
    tooltip: 'Insert cut-tag',
    onclick: function() {
    editor.insertContent('<span class="cut-tag mceNonEditable">&nbsp;</span>');
    }
  });
 });
```

It's perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to implement this for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After researching I think the key to inserting the markup cleanly may be

```
onclick: function(){
  editor.insertContent('<span class="cut-tag">&nbsp;</span> ', {format : 'raw'});
}
```

Then to prevent it from entering multiple copies also add:

```
onkeydown: function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: @AndrewAlloson Are you sure? I tried but nothing worked. And according to documentation there is not such methods as insertContentAtFocusPoint for Editor https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#editor. I got `plugin.min.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: editor.insertContentAtFocusPoint is not a function`

Comment: Try the edited answer. I'm also working on a JsFiddle demo

Comment: @AndrewAlloson  it works partinionally. But onkeydown method isn't invoked. I suppose {format : 'raw'} a little change situations. But anyway since I can change content of this tag everything breaks again